# Creating a pandas DataFrame from json object and appending a column to it

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, for-loop, json-normalize

From an API, I get information about who has filled a particular form and when they have done it as a json object. I get the below data from 2 forms `formid = ["61438732", "48247759dc"]`. The json object is stored in the `r_json_object` variable.

```json
r_json_online = {
'results': [
{'submittedAt': 1669963478503,
   'values': [{'email': 'brownsvilleselect@gmail.com'}]},
{'submittedAt': 1669963259737,
   'values': [{'email': 'brewsterdani33@gmail.com'}]},
{'submittedAt': 1669963165956,
   'values': [{'email': 'thesource95@valpo.edu'}]}
]
}
```

I have used the `json_normalize` function to de-nest the json object and insert the values into a `DataFrame` called `form_submissions`. This is the code I have used

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize
    
submissions = []

formid = ["61438732", "48247759dc"]

for i in range(0,len(formid)):
    
    submissions.extend(r_json_online["results"])

    form_submissions = pd.DataFrame()

    for j in submissions:
        form_submissions = form_submissions.append(json_normalize(j["values"]))
        form_submissions = form_submissions.append({'createdOn': j["submittedAt"]}, ignore_index=True)
        form_submissions = form_submissions.append({'formid': formid[i]}, ignore_index=True)
                 
form_submissions['createdOn'] = form_submissions['createdOn'].fillna(method = 'bfill')
form_submissions['formid'] = form_submissions['formid'].fillna(method = 'bfill')
form_submissions = form_submissions.dropna(subset= 'email')
```

**Code explanation:**

1. I have created an empty list called `submissions`
2. For each value in the formid list, I'm running the `for` loop.
3. In the `for` loop:

   a. I have added data to the submissions list
   b. Created an empty DataFrame, normalized the json object and appended the values to the DataFrame from each element in the `submissions` list

**Expected Output:**

1. I wanted the first 3 rows to have `formid = '61438732'`
2. The next 3 rows should have the `formid = '48247759dc'`

[image]

**Actual Output:**

1. The formid is the same for all the rows

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See also: ["how to format a table in a post"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716/11107541).

Comment: too much code, please reduce to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using this line " form_submissions = pd.DataFrame()" in the loop which reset your dataframe each time

Comment: Thank you! It worked when I moved it outside the loop

Comment: No probs, please mark the answer as accepted so people can see you don't need more answers

Answer (score 0):

This can easily attained by converting into two dataframes and doing cartesian product/cross merge on between both.

```
formids = ["61438732", "48247759dc"]
form_submissions_df=json_normalize(r_json_online['results'], record_path=['values'], meta=['submittedAt'])

# converting form_ids list to dataframe
form_ids_df = pd.DataFrame (formids, columns = ['form_id'])

# cross merge for cartesian product result 
form_submissions_df.merge(form_ids_df, how="cross")
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnSWk.png)